# Uncaught TypeError: useSearchParams is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm currently encountering an issue with my code, where I receive the error:

> "Uncaught Error: NextRouter was not mounted" in the console.

Upon investigating, I found that starting from Next.js version 13, we're supposed to use `next/navigation` instead of `next/router`. However, I'm not sure how to make this change. Could anyone provide some guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this?

Here's the current code:

```
import { FC } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { ShowPage } from './ShowPage';

const ProductShow: FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const productId = router.query.productId as string;

  return <ShowPage productId={productId} />;
};

export default ProductShow;
```

I've attempted to modify my code using the `useSearchParams` for getting query parameters, trying to fetch a specific `productId` from the URL and set it to a state variable.

```
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { ShowPage } from './ShowPage';

const ProductShow: FC = () => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const [productId, setProductId] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const [id,] = searchParams.entries().find(([key]) => key === 'productId');
    if (id) {
      setProductId(id);
    }
  }, [searchParams]);

  if (!productId) {
    return null;
  }

  return <ShowPage productId={productId} />;
};

export default ProductShow;
```

I expected the `productId` from the URL to be correctly fetched and set to the productId state variable. However, I encountered an issue when trying to use the find method on `searchParams.entries()`. The error message is as follows:

> Uncaught TypeError: useSearchParams is not a function or its return value is not iterable

And there also has a TypeScript error:

> Type 'IterableIterator<[string, string]>' has no property 'find'.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The last one is a TypeScript error, right? Other than the error, is it working, right?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar I apologize for the confusion, but actually, the error is not just a TypeScript issue. The application does not work and throws a runtime error as well. The console error message is as follows:

Uncaught TypeError: useSearchParams is not a function or its return value is not iterable

This suggests that useSearchParams is either not correctly imported, not a function, or its return value is not what I expect (an iterable). So there seems to be a more fundamental problem here that I need to resolve. I appreciate any suggestions or guidance.

Comment: Thanks for completing the question! I posted an answer. Check it and let me know please. Also, I edited your post so it reflects the error on which you are blocked, not the resolved one.

Answer (score 1):

[`useSearchParams`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params) returns the object `searchParams`, not an array that has `searchParams` as the first element, which is what your current code assumes. It should be:

```js
const searchParams = useSearchParams();
```

Also, you could simplify your `useEffect` code to:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const id = searchParams.get("productId");
  if (id) {
    setProductId(id);
  }
}, [searchParams]);
```

And if you are trying to get the slug of a dynamic route, use [`useParams`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-params) instead. Which works this way:

```
'use client';
 
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation';
 
export default function ExampleClientComponent() {
  const params = useParams();
 
  // Route -> /shop/[item]
  // URL -> /shop/nike-air-max-97
  // `params` -> { item: 'nike-air-max-97' }
  console.log(params);
 
  return <></>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! However, I'm currently using this URL: http://localhost:3001/products/1. Does this not apply to the solution you've provided?

Comment: My pleasure @LizLee. You seem to be using a dynamic route, in which case you get the slug with `useParams`. Check my latest edit.